# Scala type arguments do not conform to method eval's type parameter bounds

Tags: scala, generics

I'm developing Monad in Scala without type classes.

I have these traits for monad:

```scala
trait Monad[M[_], A] {
  def bind[B](f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}
trait MonadCompanion[M[_]] {
  def unit[A](a: A): M[A]
}
```

Then, I've implemented identity monad:

```scala
case class Id[A](a: A) extends Monad[Id, A] {
  override def bind[B](f: A => Id[B]): Id[B] = f(a)
}
implicit object Id extends MonadCompanion[Id] {
  def unit[A](a: A): Id[A] = Id(a)
}
```

All works correctly. Finally I have to create that generic function on Monad (following Wadler Article):

```scala
sealed trait Term
case class Constant(c: Int) extends Term
case class Div(t1: Term, t2: Term) extends Term

lazy val answer = Div(Div(Constant(1972), Constant(2)), Constant(23))

def eval[M[_] <: Monad[M,Int]](e : Term)(implicit companion: MonadCompanion[M]) : M[Int] = e match {
  case Constant(a) => companion.unit(a)
  case Div(t, u) => eval(t).bind((a  : Int) => eval(u).bind((b : Int) => companion.unit(a / b)))
}
```

But here's the problem: when I try to call eval, compiler say

```
type arguments [Id] do not conform to method eval's type parameter bounds [M[_] <: Monad[M,Int]]
      println(Id.unit(answer).bind(eval[Id](_)(Id)))
```

Moreover, I have problem with implicit:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter companion: MonadCompanion[M]
      println(Id.unit(answer).bind(eval))
```

How can I overtake those?

Comment: Provide definitions of `Term`, `Constant`, `Div`.

Comment: Actually can't reproduce. The code compiles without errors https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/YJXijFYpR863aVymvlTJYA

Comment: Aha, I see. The problematic line is `Id.unit(answer).bind(eval[Id](_)(Id))`. What is `answer`?

Comment: Sorry:

`lazy val answer = Div(Div(Constant(1972), Constant(2)), Constant(23))`

Comment: _"I'm developing Monad in Scala without type classes"_ what is even the point of this? Just makes the code more complex, break a basic understanding of those concepts; `Id` **is not** a `Monad`, `Id` **forms** a `Monad` _(together with proper implementation of the functions and formal proofs of the laws)_, or commonly expressed, `Id` **has an instance** of `Monad` associated with it. - And also, at the end you are still using a typeclass to get `unit` because subtyping polymorphism is unable to express operations on the type itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bound `M[_] <: Monad[M, Int]` means "no matter what argument `X` I give `M`, `M[X] <: Monad[M, Int]`. That's not right. The bound should be `M[X] <: Monad[M, X]`: "no matter what argument `X` I give `M`, `M[X] <: Monad[M, X]`". `X` is local variable that is declared simply by being named in the bound and goes out of scope after the bound. Also, the recursive calls need `M` specified:

```
def eval[M[X] <: Monad[M, X]](e : Term)(implicit companion: MonadCompanion[M]) : M[Int] = e match {
  case Constant(a) => companion.unit(a)
  case Div(t, u) => eval[M](t).bind(a => eval[M](u).bind(b => companion.unit(a / b)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you can modify type bound

```
def eval[M[A] <: Monad[M,A]]...
```